# shortest distance from moving point in parabola to point

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, optimization, conic-sections

P is the moving point on the following parabola and Q is fixed point (-1,8) .calculate shortest distance between p and q

$2x=y^2$

$x=\frac{y^2}{2}$

$d= \sqrt{(y-8)^2 + (x+1)^2}$

$d^2= (y-8)^2 + (\frac{y^2}{2}+1)^2$

$d^2= 2y^2-16y+\frac{y^4}{4}+65$

$d`=4y-16+y^3=0$

$y=16$ or $y=\sqrt{12}$

$y^2=2x$

$16^2=2x$

$x=128$

$y^2+4=16$

$(128,16)$

$y^2=12$

$y=\sqrt{12}$

$(6,\sqrt{12})$

is this right?

Comment: How did you get $y=16$? Or $\sqrt{12}$? None of them are OK. And a cubic equation has one real and two complex solution or three real solutions.

Comment: @Andrei is it possible to do, $4y+y^3=16$ , $y(4+y^2)=16$ ?

Comment: Yes, but the answer is not what you expect. $16(4+16^2)$ is much greater than $16$

Comment: Try rational root theorem

Comment: @Andrei ok thankyou , how can i find the factor of 4y-16+y^3=0?

Comment: Using rational root theorem, one of the factors for $y^3+4y-16$ is $y=2$. Check if the other two solutions are real

Comment: @Andrei $(y-2)(y^2+2y+8)$ ?  the other is not real (?) so the answer is just y=2?

Comment: Correct. you have only one extremum

Answer (score 1):

No, it's wrong.

The equation $y^3+4y-16=0$ gives $y=2$.

My solution.

By your work and by AM-GM
$$d=\sqrt{(y-8)^2+\left(\frac{y^2}{2}+1\right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{y^4}{4}+2y^2-16y+65}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{y^4}{4}+2\cdot y^2+5\cdot4-16y+45}\geq\sqrt{8\sqrt[8]{\frac{y^4}{4}\cdot(y^2)^2\cdot4^5}-16y+45}=$$
$$=\sqrt{16|y|-16y+45}\geq\sqrt{45}=3\sqrt5.$$
The equality occurs for $y=2$, which says that $3\sqrt5$ is a minimal value.